Spherical cap "density" problem

$T$ is the region that is inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and above the plane $z = 1$. Consider the following integral on the region $T$:
$$I=\iiint_T \sqrt{x^2+y^2}dV$$
A) Write $I$ in cylindrical coordinates.
B) Write $I$ in spherical coordinates.

When I tried using an integral calculator to verify if both my answers got the same value. Here's what I got in A:
$$\int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0^\sqrt{3} \int_1^\sqrt{4-r^2} r^2\, dzdrd\theta\approx 4.997$$
(Added parentheses to separate the Jacobian from the function.)
And in B I found:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})}\int_{\sec(\phi)}^2 p\sin (\phi) p^2\cos(\phi)\, dpd\phi d\theta=\frac{9\pi}{4}\approx7.068$$
Those integrals are way harder than the others in the exercise list. I even tried following along some similar questions on youtube and I can't find what I did wrong on this question.
Here's an image that shows how I got the limits of integration:


Check your Jacobian again.

Specifically, recheck the Jacobian on your spherical integral.

Just FYI on notation - The radial variable in spherical coordinates is actually the greek letter rho, $\rho$, not the english letter $p$.

The evaluation in cylindrical coordinates is correct. As regards the spherical coordinates, the correct Jacobian should be $\rho^2\sin(\phi)$. The Jacobian is $\rho^2\cos(\phi)$ when $\phi$ denotes the latitude. Therefore
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})}\int_{\sec(\phi)}^2\int_0^{2\pi} \rho\sin(\phi)\cdot \color{blue}{\rho^2\sin(\phi)}\, d\theta d\rho d\phi 
&=2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\sin^2(\phi)\left[ \frac{\rho^4}{4}\right]_{\sec(\phi)}^2 d\phi\\
&=2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\left( 4\sin^2(\phi)-\frac{\tan^2(\phi)}{4\cos^2(\phi)}\right) d\phi\\
&=2\pi\left[ -\sin(2\phi)+2\phi-\frac{\tan^3(\phi)}{12}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\\
&=2\pi\left( -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\\
&=\frac{4\pi^2}{3}-\frac{3\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\approx 4.997375398
\end{align}
which coincides with the evaluation in cylindrical coordinates.
